# Is function $f(z)=|z-9|$ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Is function $f(z)=|z-9|$ differentiable?

For a function to be differentiable in $\mathbb{C}$, it must satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations:

$$\begin{cases}u_x=v_y \\ u_y = - v_x \end{cases}$$

Let $f(z)=|x+iy-9|=\sqrt{(x-9)^2+y^2}$. This means that $u(x,y)=\sqrt{(x-9)^2+y^2}$ and $v(x,y)=0$. Then
$u_x = \frac{x-9}{(x-9)^2+y^2}$ and $u_y=\frac{y}{\sqrt{(x-9)^2+y^2}}$. $v_x=v_y=0$ for $z \ne 9$

I am not sure what to do next. Also i don't know what to do about point $z=9$.

Comment: Does $f$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: Hint : The absolute value function $g(z)=|z|$ is not differentiable at $z=0$.

Comment: I assume that by "found the Cauchy Riemann equations" you mean "I have identified $u$ and $v$ and substituted them in" - if so, could you include that in your question please? (if not, do that!)

Comment: As mentioned in the other comments, have you tried identifying $u$ and $v$? If so, what are they, and what stops you from investigating the Cauchy–Riemann equation? Can you show us what you have tried in this respect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use the Cauchy-Riemann equations here. The function $f$ is not differentiable at $9$ because the limit$$\lim_{z\to9}\frac{f(z)-f(9)}{z-9}=\lim_{z\to9}\frac{|z-9|}{z-9}$$doesn't exist. It is equal to $1$ if $z\in 9+\Bbb R$  and it is equal to $-i$ if $z\in9+i\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

If you move from a point $z$ in a direction at a right angle to the line from $9$ to $z,$ you see that the rate of change of $|z-9|$ is $0.$ But if you move directly along that line, the rate of change is $1.$ Since $0$ and $1$ are not both the same number, this function is not differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=|z-9|=\sqrt{(x-9)^2 +y^2} $
$$u(x, y) =\sqrt{(x-9)^2 +y^2}$$

$$v(x, y) =0$$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{(x-9)^2 +y^2} } (x -9)$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{(x-9)^2 +y^2} } y$

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ doesn't exists at the point $z=(9, 0)$, hence the function $f$ doesn't satisfy C-R equation at $z=9$ and so $f$ not Holomorphic at $z=9$.

$f:D\to \mathbb{C} $ is Holomorphic on $D\subset {\mathbb{C}} $ open set. Then $f$ satisfy C-R equations.

By Contrapositive argument, if $f$ doesn't satisfy C-R equations at $z_0$ implies $f$ is not Holomorphic at $z_0 \in D$

Answer (score 0):

The slickest argument here is based on the following fact:

*If a function $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ always takes real values and is differentiable, then it is constant.*

Since $|z-9|$ always takes real values and is *not* constant, it cannot be differentiable.

You can prove the italicized fact directly from the Cauchy-Riemann equations with less calculation than it would take to argue from the particular definition of $|z-9|$. Since you're assuming the function takes only real values, two of $u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ (which ones?) will be zero. Then Cauch and Riemann claim the two others are zero too, and two applications of the familiar *real* mean value theorem now tells you that the function value must be the same at any two complex points.

Comment: Yes sir. $f : D\subset {\mathbb{C}} \to \mathbb{C}$ Holomorphic and $f(D) \subset \mathbb{R}$ , then $f$ must be constant function.

Comment: Slickness of an argument is inversely proportional to the megatonnage of the theorem applied in the argument.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Hmm, I was about to defend it alternatively as "more instructive" than getting bogged down in computing the partial derivatives. But perhaps it is actually more memorable for the student to waste the time of computing them, only to find afterwards that he actually just needs to know if they're identically zero ...